# Cannot access json data in component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to get json data from a XMLHttpRequest and it works well so I see the data in the console. But the component which should show these data doesnt show any... Is there anything wrong? Maybe it's wrong to call the function in mounted()? I called it in created() too but nothing changed... Any ideas?

in script

```
    data(){
       return{
        json: {}
       }
    }

    mounted(){
     var gsRef = firebase.storage().refFromURL('XXXXXXXXX')
   gsRef.child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid+'.json').getDownloadURL().then(function(url){
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
            xhr.responseType = 'json'
            xhr.onload = function() {
              this.json = xhr.response
              console.log(this.json.user) //works shows the data!
            }
            xhr.open('GET',url)
            xhr.send()
          })
      }
```

in template

```
<h1>{{json.user}}</h1> //doenst work. Cannot access data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"this" is probably referring to the wrong context (i.e. not the vue instance). Try saving a reference to the proper `this` before your firebase call, something like `const self = this`, and then use `self.json` to set the data.

```
mounted(){
     var self = this
     var gsRef = firebase.storage().refFromURL('XXXXXXXXX')
   gsRef.child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid+'.json').getDownloadURL().then(function(url){
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
            xhr.responseType = 'json'
            xhr.onload = function() {
              self.json = xhr.response
              console.log(self.json.user) //works shows the data!
            }
            xhr.open('GET',url)
            xhr.send()
          })
      }
```